# Absolute values of fourier transform of noise-charged RLC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, noise, resonance, fourier

I am doing time-domain simulations of currents in a parallel RLC circuit charged by thermal noise. In detail in pseudo-code:

```
dt = 1e-9
T = 20 // temperature
R = 230e6
L = 3e-3
C = 20e-12
df = 1/2 f_Nyq = 1/(2 dt) // df is Nyquist frequency


for(int i=0; i<number_of_steps; i++){
 Inoise = sqrt(4 kb T R df) * G(µ=0, sigma=1) // Gauss with zero mean and stddev of 1 to 
                                              // make subsequent values uncorrelated
 // Solve differential equation with U = L * IL, IR = L/R IL', IC = L*C * IL''
 Solve[IL + IC + IR = Inoise]  
 Save(t=i*dt, IL, IC, IR)
}
```

Based on these values I calculate the FFT of the voltage $$ U = L \cdot \dot I_L$$ (which is the same for all components). I use the normalized discrete FFT function.

For certain values of L, C and R I am getting a beautiful resonance curve as depicted here:[image]

Now the maximum value should in theory be equal to $$ U_{max} = \sqrt{4 k_B T R \Delta f}$$. However, the value I get out for U_max is a factor of ~1.6 to small (with df taken into account). I happen to notice that
$$1.6^2 = \sqrt{2\pi} $$
but I don't see why this factor should be there. This factor is invariant under change of any of the variables.

Does anyone have an idea where something goes wrong?

Comment: Look carefully at the definitions of FFT and inverse FFT functions you are using. There is not a unique convention about where to put the 1/(2*Pi). Some put it on the IFFT (or even the FFT); some split it equally between FFT and IFFT with sqrt() on each. A misunderstanding between conventions might explain your observed result.

Comment: Testable : what does the FFT of  a sinewave, amplitude 1, at your centre frequency, look like?

Comment: @Brian shouldn't this factor not appear at all for discrete FFTs?

Comment: I think that places you in the " put it on the IFFT" camp...

Comment: What I actually meant that this factor should not be there in discrete FFTs or iFFTs at all, only in the continuous case.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Also, I tested it as you suggested and indeed, a sine-wave of amplitude 1 results in an FFT value of amplitude 0.5. I guess the fft()-function I am using assumes some hidden convention regarding one-sided and two-sided PSDs...

Comment: Interesting ... neither 1 nor 1/1.6 ... hmmm you may need to delve into that fft() or replace it, to get what you want. Or live with it as calibrated by test.